# SAML IDP Login Form not prompted after local logout

Tags: spring, local, logout, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am using spring saml sample application (by @vladimir schafer) to test my single sign on with an IDP. I am using IDP initiated single sign on. When I start the sign on process for the first time, I am able to get IDP login page and is successfully logged into the application. However, when I local logout and login again, it doesn't prompt me the IDP login form. It logs me in directly.

Am I missing something here? Or is this how the saml application supposed to work?

I want to local logout and when user logs in again, it should prompt the IDP login for.

I have edited securityContext.xml to include `<security:logout logout-url="/j_logout" logout-success-url="/logout.jsp"/>`, no luck.

My form action is `/saml/logout?local=true`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something here? Or is this how the saml application
>   supposed to work?

Yes, that's how the SAML supposed to work.

> I want to local log out and when user logs in again, it should prompt
>   the IDP login for.

No, you can't do it. If you want IDP prompt the login page, use global log out. For more details, local log out only invalidates your application session, not IDP session or other application sessions. Therefore, when to redirecting to IDP login page, it already has session information about who you are so you don't need to log in again.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Our requirement is to have a local logout and not global. if this is how it works, then it is a potential security threat as any one can get into application as far as IDP session is on. I will have to think about some other solution.

Comment: Is there a way I can request IDP to prompt the login form?. I was thinking to check if my local session is old or new. If it is new, then ask IDP to prompt the login form. Not sure if we have such feature in SAML.

Comment: That's not in SAML specification. Thus you can do that as long as implementing your IDP and it won't work with other IDP.